# How to troubleshoot which transitive dependency's POM is referring to a defunct Maven repository?

Tags: maven

With Maven 3.0.3 I'm getting a "Could not resolve dependencies..." error for a project I'm working on:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project arquillian-jetty-embedded-6.1: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project 
org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-jetty-embedded-6.1:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: 
Failed to collect dependencies for [
org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-spi:jar:1.0.0.CR1-SNAPSHOT (compile), 
org.jboss.arquillian.container:arquillian-container-test-spi:jar:1.0.0.CR1-SNAPSHOT (compile), 
org.jboss.arquillian.protocol:arquillian-protocol-servlet:jar:1.0.0.CR1-SNAPSHOT (compile), 
org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-cdi:jar:1.0.0.CR1-SNAPSHOT (compile), 
org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-resource:jar:1.0.0.CR1-SNAPSHOT (compile), 
org.jboss.arquillian.testenricher:arquillian-testenricher-initialcontext:jar:1.0.0.CR1-SNAPSHOT (compile), 
org.jboss.shrinkwrap.container:shrinkwrap-container-jetty-60:jar:1.0.0-beta-1 (compile), 
org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.12 (provided), 
org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:6.1.12 (provided), 
org.jboss.arquillian.junit:arquillian-junit-container:jar:1.0.0.CR1-SNAPSHOT (test), 
junit:junit:jar:4.8.1 (test), 
javax.enterprise:cdi-api:jar:1.0 (test), 
org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-naming:jar:6.1.12 (test), 
org.glassfish.web:el-impl:jar:2.2 (test), 
javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.2 (test), 
com.h2database:h2:jar:1.2.138 (test), 
org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven:jar:1.0.0-beta-2 (test)]: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jboss.interceptor:jboss-interceptor-api:jar:1.1: 
Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.interceptor:jboss-interceptor-api:pom:1.1 
from/to repository.jboss.org (http://repository.jboss.org/maven2): 
Access denied to: 
http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/interceptor/jboss-interceptor-api/1.1/jboss-interceptor-api-1.1.pom -> 
[Help 1]
```

I know the error is occurring because a [dead repository is being referenced](http://community.jboss.org/en/build/blog/2011/06/01/blocking-repositoryjbossorgmaven2), and that I can work around it by configuring an active mirror for that repository in my settings.xml.  I know the artifact in question, jboss-interceptor-api, is not a direct dependency of the project I'm working on, nor is the project referencing the dead repository directly.  What's not clear is how could I determine the offending transitive dependency and its lineage to the project in question?  I'd like to correct the underlying issue, or at least inform those who could.

I've searched my local repository and found several references to the dead repo, but none of those artifacts are amongst the dependencies listed in the above error message.  I get the error trying to run `mvn -U dependency:tree` on the project, so no help there either.  I'm also not seeing any clues in the `-X` debug output, though I could post it all if desired.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but here are some ideas.  Have you tried loading the project in an IDE?  I know intellij lets you see a dependency graph.  Maybe it'd work.  Also, it may show you the error on the dependency that's causing all the problems.  Or, maybe if you mirrored the repository you'd be able to do a dependency:tree and find the bad dependency.

Comment: What is not clear to me is what you mean by : "dependency referring to a defunct maven repo". Unless special configuration (in a complex parent pom for instance), a dependency is not bound to a repo, but instead maven searches in its known repos to resolve the missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

What Samuel says is not true -- any pom.xml file can include a `<repositories>` stanza to define a repo that it will pull artifacts from.  It is not a best practice (or even  an acceptable one!), but it does happen.  I had this happen with some pre-released EclipseLink artifacts a while back.

However, since we know the offending POM has been downloaded to your machine (else Maven wouldn't complain) then search your local `~/.m2` first for any poms that hols a `<repositories>` stanza.  On Linux, I'd do this:

`grep -r \<repositories\> .`

and then I'd start looking through all those suspect files.  I have a pretty big project, but running that command on my machine results in only 30 offending poms.

I'm and sure an `awk` expert could give you a better command to run that would return those potential files and search them again for the invalid repo.

Anyway, hope this helps.